# How to store a value from a request and check upon a response in java cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber

I am using cucumber java and I am unable to determine how to grab a value from my request and validate it within the response.

For example, in my feature file:

```
When I use numbers 123
Then the response matches the request
```

So I have the code to pass through my request:

```
@Step
public void searchUsingNumber(String number) throws Exception{
    validatableResponse = with()
            .baseUri("https://xxx")
            .param("numbers", number)
            .get().then();
}
```

In my step definition it is set like that:

```
@When("^I use numbers \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void iUseNumbers(String number) throws Throwable {
    eventsMethods.searchUsingNumber(number);
}
```

This outputs 123.

No I want to look in my response in the Then statement:

```
    public String number() {
        String number = validatableResponse.extract().jsonPath().get("number").toString();
        log.info("number is: " + number);
        return number;
    }

------------

    @Then("^the response matches the request$")
    public void theResponseMatchesTheRequest(){
        String number= eventsMethods.number();

    }
```

This outputs 123. But I want to perform an assertion in the Then statement to check the response 123 matches with the 123 in the request. In other words get the value from the when statement and assert against the value from the response.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Scenario Outline:`

in the feature file

```
Scenario Outline: test the response
  Given the compute page is open
  When I use numbers "<number>"
  Then the response matches the request "<number>"
  Examples: 
    | number |
    | 123    |
    | 42     |
```

the glue code

```
@When("^I use numbers \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void iUseNumbers(String number) throws Throwable {
    ...
}

@Then("^the response matches the request \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void theResponseMatchesTheRequest(String number) throws Throwable {
    ...
}
```